# Create a balloon tool tip for text box?

Tags: java, swt

How to create a balloon tool tip for a text box in SWT?

Comment: StackOverflow only clarrifies your problem in your solution.You have to provide the source code of whatever you have tried or explain the context little bit clearly.

Comment: @ Selva:Downvote: your question is of low quality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a modified SWT snippet which shows how to add balloon tooltip to SWT `Text` instance.

Next time please consider to ask more specifically, I don't now, if this is what are you looking for..

```
/*
 * Tooltip example snippet: create a balloon tooltip for a tray item
 *
 * For a list of all SWT example snippets see
 * http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/
 * 
 * @since 3.2
 */
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolTip;

public class TextFieldTooltip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
        final ToolTip tip = new ToolTip(shell, SWT.BALLOON);
        tip.setMessage("Here is a message for the user. When the message is too long it wraps. I should say something cool but nothing comes to my mind.");

        Text tfTooltip = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        tfTooltip.setText("sample text field");
        tfTooltip.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                tip.setVisible(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                Text actionWidget = (Text) e.widget;
                Point loc = actionWidget.toDisplay(actionWidget.getLocation());
                tip.setLocation(loc.x + actionWidget.getSize().x - actionWidget.getBorderWidth(), loc.y);
                tip.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        Text tfNext = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        tfNext.setText("TF without tooltip");
        shell.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with default tooltip location? Did you want to show it to the right side of the widget?

Comment: `Point loc = shell.toDisplay(actionWidget.getLocation());`
A widget's location is defined in its parent coordinate system, so call toDisplay() on parent instance.

Answer (score 3):

For a standard os tooltip, use:

> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setToolTipText(String)

For example,

```
    final Text textArea = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    textArea.setToolTipText("Standard tooltip \n for swt control.");
```

Here what it would look like on Windows 7:

[image]