# How can i get a balloon in my custom tool tip?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am creating a custom tooltip where i have a textbox.I am able to do that but i could not get balloon like icon as in the attached picture .Can anyone help me regarding this.

Mytooltip class:

```
public class MyToolTip extends ToolTip {
    private Shell parentShell;

    public MyToolTip(Control control) {
        super(control,SWT.BALLOON,false);
        this.parentShell = control.getShell();
    }


    @Override
    protected Composite createToolTipContentArea(Event event, Composite parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Composite comp = new Composite(parent,SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Text text = new Text(comp,SWT.BORDER);
        text.setText("");

        return comp;
    }
}
```

Class using tooltip:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setText("sample text field");

    MyToolTip myTooltipLabel = new MyToolTip(text);
    myTooltipLabel.setShift(new Point(-5, -5));
    myTooltipLabel.setHideOnMouseDown(false);
    myTooltipLabel.activate();

    myTooltipLabel.setRespectDisplayBounds(false);

    myTooltipLabel.setRespectMonitorBounds(false);
```

[image: Balloon image]

Comment: I guess you are referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8531537/1449199) answer to a different question. It works for me on Windows 7. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Baz I am talking about custom tooltip so in the  code i am extending tootip class but i am not getting balloon ..I hope it clears my query little bit better

Comment: Well, you didn't answer my question. Furthermore: Why don't you use the code in the answer I posted above?

Comment: @Baz Actually i want a textbox widget in the tooltip  which can be editable. i will not get this features in the  code you pasted...Hope now it is  clear.And i am using windows7 ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip` whereas the code that was used to create that screenshot uses `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolTip`.

The SWT tooltip can have the balloon look by passing `SWT.BALLOON` as the style bit.

The JFace tooltip does not support `SWT.BALLOON`, only `ToolTip.NO_RECREATE` and `ToolTip.RECREATE`.

So here is the conclusion: You can't subclass the swt tooltip to make it editable. You can't make the JFace tooltip look the way you want it to look. The only solution that is left is creating your own `Widget` based on `Composite` or `Canvas` that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for solving my query.. I will look for some other possible ways

Comment: @Rajesh You're welcome. Sorry, I couldn't provide you with a workaround. If you find a solution, please post it here as an answer. If not, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: @Rajesh have you found an adequate solution yet?
I also tried to get similar behavior except for the balloon looks using org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip but it disappears when moving the mouse outside of the control which is not what I wanted; I want it to show while typing.
An alternative - again without balloon looks - is to use Mylyn's AbstractNotificationPopup which can contain any content, and set it's location by overriding initializeBounds(). Unfortunately still suffers from a bug where it appears on main monitor only https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213978

Comment: Best alternatives I have found that don't have the balloon look but do have info popup behavior is to create a Window from scratch using style SWT.TOOL | SWT.NO_FOCUS, or using JFaces PopupDialog, see e.g. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073187/creation-of-infopopup-in-eclipse.html