# How to find in SWT when user moves away from a shell?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm opening a `ToolTip` like shell with `SWT.NO_TRIM` which just shows some additional info when the user clicks an item in the main window. The problem is, if the user clicks away from both the main and tooltip window, e.g by doing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then the tooltip window remains open and doesn't go away. How can I detect when the user has switched away, e.g by doing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>?

Comment: Can you maybe add some code to reproduce the issue? Isn't [`SWT.FocusOut`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#FocusOut) what you are looking for?

Comment: Attach a `FocusListener` on your "item in the main window", and `tooltip.setVisible(false)` in the `focusLost` delegating method. [You can also check out this cool example here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517739/how-to-create-a-balloon-tool-tip-for-text-box-in-swt) Just for the kicks, what OS are you using? I had some similar issues with tooltips on MacOS.